# Docker is not loading the correct Dockerfile when uploading to aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

For some reason when i upload to aws-eb using the CLI, aws is not recognizing the latest Dockerfile.

this is my current Dockerfile::

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11.3

USER root

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

# Environment specific requirements
# ARG ENVIRONMENT
# ENV CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
# COPY requirements-${ENVIRONMENT}.txt /app/
# RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements-${ENVIRONMENT}.txt

COPY requirements-aws.txt /app/
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements-aws.txt


EXPOSE 80

ENV NAME World

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

notice that there are multiple lines commented out.

when i try to deploy to aws eb using the following command i see a failure::

```
docker build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=aws -t qube-dev-env:latest .

eb deploy qube-dev-env


[+] Building 55.9s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                             docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 578B                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.3                                                                                5.3s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                               0.6s
 => => transferring context: 49.82MB                                                                                                            0.6s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11.3@sha256:3a619e3c96fd4c5fc5e1998fd4dcb1f1403eb90c4c6409c70d7e80b9468df7df                         14.6s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.11.3@sha256:3a619e3c96fd4c5fc5e1998fd4dcb1f1403eb90c4c6409c70d7e80b9468df7df                          0.0s
 => => sha256:3a619e3c96fd4c5fc5e1998fd4dcb1f1403eb90c4c6409c70d7e80b9468df7df 2.14kB / 2.14kB                                                  0.0s
 => => sha256:de5aeca5458519a772e9b344d3c1ac16a1be52eab179cf2a28a31382dd1018f1 2.01kB / 2.01kB                                                  0.0s
 => => sha256:1918a277862c33ee6f35b696867ca414a014f2b63f1e257986a3f480c9da5edc 7.54kB / 7.54kB                                                  0.0s
 => => sha256:b04fae59f135dd79280e4a6da39408e04c6d703c617cbcb1c524dfe6f2962fe5 53.69MB / 53.69MB                                                3.9s
 => => sha256:24cef00b9ad96bea3be667b285f4b22763747912cc8e4f2c3f145facb418d71d 15.75MB / 15.75MB                                                1.4s
 => => sha256:1db91b65282bc9aae941329f294e69b2671a6429827e8b357b950a2c112ef783 54.68MB / 54.68MB                                                4.0s
 => => sha256:54db3e52d959511497ff15bfc413d13a6743a3cb6a314971f1b31be790e2b347 189.78MB / 189.78MB                                              9.4s
 => => extracting sha256:b04fae59f135dd79280e4a6da39408e04c6d703c617cbcb1c524dfe6f2962fe5                                                       1.6s
 => => sha256:4d727a249b449ca216ff6e0b6f53a712285395ca26c1ad7ed98aebe0548bf250 6.40MB / 6.40MB                                                  4.6s
 => => sha256:7b002b13bbef73ae5658d4cdbbdbec09d48037321e59e342f789d545a1f39435 19.88MB / 19.88MB                                                5.5s
 => => sha256:1458f81f1e48ac5402ce72b71eb02f04928830b64454646af2292d44360d276c 245B / 245B                                                      4.7s
 => => sha256:b9e4920f6c0eb011598fed3c9e87be40020fd50e11da5696c2ca6d3e8d614326 3.08MB / 3.08MB                                                  5.3s
 => => extracting sha256:24cef00b9ad96bea3be667b285f4b22763747912cc8e4f2c3f145facb418d71d                                                       0.3s
 => => extracting sha256:1db91b65282bc9aae941329f294e69b2671a6429827e8b357b950a2c112ef783                                                       1.6s
 => => extracting sha256:54db3e52d959511497ff15bfc413d13a6743a3cb6a314971f1b31be790e2b347                                                       4.0s
 => => extracting sha256:4d727a249b449ca216ff6e0b6f53a712285395ca26c1ad7ed98aebe0548bf250                                                       0.2s
 => => extracting sha256:7b002b13bbef73ae5658d4cdbbdbec09d48037321e59e342f789d545a1f39435                                                       0.4s
 => => extracting sha256:1458f81f1e48ac5402ce72b71eb02f04928830b64454646af2292d44360d276c                                                       0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:b9e4920f6c0eb011598fed3c9e87be40020fd50e11da5696c2ca6d3e8d614326                                                       0.2s
 => [2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                          0.2s
 => [3/5] ADD . /app                                                                                                                            0.2s
 => [4/5] COPY requirements-aws.txt /app/                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [5/5] RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements-aws.txt                                                               33.3s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                          2.2s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                         2.2s
 => => writing image sha256:616032b13b64435a06be93e0ea2c534f971fe487d0ea91d0b98c28511a230808                                                    0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/qube-dev-env:latest                                                                                          0.0s

What's Next?
  View summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview
Creating application version archive "app-cf84-230811_092300".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2023-08-11 14:23:05    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2023-08-11 14:23:10    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2023-08-11 14:23:17    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2023-08-11 14:23:17    ERROR   Instance deployment failed to build the Docker image. The deployment failed.
2023-08-11 14:23:20    ERROR   [Instance: i-0ff7ae8699d3ed249] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2023-08-11 14:23:20    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2023-08-11 14:23:21    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0ff7ae8699d3ed249'. Aborting the operation.
2023-08-11 14:23:21    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        
                                                                      
ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
juan@192 docwise %
```

this is what i see in the eb-engine.logs::

```
2023/08/11 14:23:14.761205 [INFO] successfully execute command: docker pull python:3.11.3
2023/08/11 14:23:14.761208 [INFO] successfully pulled docker image python:3.11.3
2023/08/11 14:23:14.761211 [INFO] start to build docker image
2023/08/11 14:23:14.761226 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker build -t aws_beanstalk/staging-app /var/app/staging/
2023/08/11 14:23:16.805032 [INFO] Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.43MB

Step 1/10 : FROM python:3.11.3
 ---> 0a6cd0db41a4
Step 2/10 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3d709572dfae
Step 3/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 80c16bb6def2
Step 4/10 : ADD . /app
 ---> 6fa732676a8d
Step 5/10 : ARG ENVIRONMENT
 ---> Running in 5afc70e03b57
Removing intermediate container 5afc70e03b57
 ---> 39e746755abd
Step 6/10 : COPY requirements-${ENVIRONMENT}.txt /app/

2023/08/11 14:23:16.805062 [INFO] COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat requirements-.txt: file does not exist

2023/08/11 14:23:16.805068 [WARN] failed to execute command: docker build -t aws_beanstalk/staging-app /var/app/staging/, retrying...
2023/08/11 14:23:16.805079 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker build -t aws_beanstalk/staging-app /var/app/staging/
2023/08/11 14:23:17.430875 [INFO] Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.43MB

Step 1/10 : FROM python:3.11.3
 ---> 0a6cd0db41a4
Step 2/10 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3d709572dfae
Step 3/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 80c16bb6def2
Step 4/10 : ADD . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6fa732676a8d
Step 5/10 : ARG ENVIRONMENT
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 39e746755abd
Step 6/10 : COPY requirements-${ENVIRONMENT}.txt /app/

2023/08/11 14:23:17.430896 [INFO] COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat requirements-.txt: file does not exist

2023/08/11 14:23:17.430918 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to build docker image: Command /bin/sh -c docker build -t aws_beanstalk/staging-app /var/app/staging/ failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat requirements-.txt: file does not exist
 

2023/08/11 14:23:17.430924 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2023/08/11 14:23:17.431014 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed to build the Docker image. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1691763797430,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1691763797430,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

2023/08/11 14:23:17.431205 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy

2023/08/11 14:24:48.990680 [INFO] Starting...
2023/08/11 14:24:48.990728 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2023/08/11 14:24:48.990744 [INFO] reading event message file
2023/08/11 14:24:48.991059 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2023/08/11 14:24:49.060651 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:577826555055:stack/awseb-e-awfznfc3uk-stack/06248900-3608-11ee-af9e-0a33453b6fc1 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-1
2023/08/11 14:24:49.575959 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:577826555055:stack/awseb-e-awfznfc3uk-stack/06248900-3608-11ee-af9e-0a33453b6fc1 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-east-1
2023/08/11 14:24:49.937645 [INFO] checking whether command bundle-log is applicable to this instance...
2023/08/11 14:24:49.937658 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2023/08/11 14:24:49.937661 [INFO] Engine command: (bundle-log)

2023/08/11 14:24:49.937854 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetBundleLogs
2023/08/11 14:24:49.937861 [INFO] Bundle Logs...
```

I dont have a .ebignore file
I dont have a Dockerrun.aws.json file
I did a 'Rebuild environment on aws eb but that didn't work

if I zip all the files and the upload them on the eb console, everything works.

not sure what the issue is here..

we also tried creating a separate env and uploading the data there and we ran into the same issue.

I can run the file locally perfect.

any advice is welcome